# capybara-webkit doesn't run test anymore

Tags: rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I just updated Capybara (0.13.0) and Rspec (2.12.0) and now my capybara-webkit tests only work about 1/5 of the time.

By "not work", I mean the contents of the test isn't run at all. It just freezes on that test. It doesn't seem to be doing anything (the Ruby process is only using 0.1% cpu).

Also, some of my `js: true` tests seem to work 100% of the time.

When I just run the tests in Firefox, everything works.

Anyone else have this problem? Any ideas on how to debug it?

Comment: Have you looked at the [issues](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues?page=1&state=open) for capybara, such as [this one](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/848)?